# Django translations work on dev and heroku, not ec2

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, internationalization, gunicorn

I have a django app that is deployed on heroku, but for technical reasons I need to move over to ec2.

I have translations that work on my local computer and on heroku, but WILL NOT work on EC2 (Amazon Linux). My .mo files ARE NOT git ignored. Just in case, I recompiled on the new server.

My locale path points to the correct dir - I print it out after setting it and it matches.

I have checked many many posts, and nothing helps. Any ideas?

I'm serving the app with gunicorn & nginx.

Comment: Can you please tell me why you -1 this post? If it's so simple, maybe you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the settings file - it was copied from dev and switched the paths to windows style!